# Errors when added backend listener to JMeter 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter

```
2020-07-30 17:01:29,273 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-07-30 17:01:29,274 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-07-30 17:01:29,275 INFO o.a.j.v.b.BackendListener: Backend Listener: Starting worker with class: class io.github.delirius325.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchBackendClient and queue capacity: 5000
2020-07-30 17:01:29,276 INFO o.a.j.v.b.BackendListener: Backend Listener: Started  worker with class: class io.github.delirius325.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchBackendClient
2020-07-30 17:01:29,277 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,6,main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed calling setupTest
```